# Error executing Powershell commandlets using C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, powershell

I have the following code that I have tested and works:

```
    using (new Impersonator("Administrator", "dev.dev", #########"))
    {
        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);

        runspace.Open();

        RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
        scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        Command myCmd = new Command(@"C:\test.ps1");
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("upn", upn));
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("sipAddress", sipAddress));
        pipeline.Commands.Add(myCmd);

        // Execute PowerShell script
        Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
    }
```

However, when I try to include the function in a different project so that it is called from a webservice it throws an execption:

```
    System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied.
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What were you planning on doing with the impersonator object? Since at the moment you do not seem to be using it...

Comment: It was my attempt to fix the problem. It was posted as a solution for a similar problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's happening is that Impersonator only impersonates on the thread, and PowerShell's Runspace is running on another thread.

To make this work, you need to add:

```
runspace.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
runspace.ThreadOptions = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;
```

just before you open the runspace.

This will force the runspace to run on the same thread as the impersonated token.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Indeed I did.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I couldn't found any namespace for the ThreadOptions.

Comment: That's because I made a typo.  The class is System.Management.Automation.PSThreadOptions

Answer (score 1):

Use these namespaces :

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Threading;
```

Create Runspace with InitialSessionState

```
InitialSessionState initialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
initialSessionState.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
initialSessionState.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;

using ( Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace ( initialSessionState ) )
{
  runspace.Open();

  // scripts invocation                 

  runspace.Close();
}
```