# Powershell via ASP.Net - "The '=' operator failed: Access is denied."

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

I'm attempting to run Powershell scripts through a web interface coded in C#/ASP.Net.  I'm leaving my .ps1 scripts intact and calling them through Process.Start(Powershell);.

The error I receive every time is "The '=' operator failed: Access is denied."  The powershell script portion that fails is on "$LC = Get-Credential" - assignment works everywhere else.  Note: This only fails when running through published .aspx on IIS7 webserver.  It works correctly when debugging through Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks!

Comment: isnt obvious that the  Get-Credential fails to runs ? because your acount did not have the permission to get credentials ?

Comment: The account has permissions to get-credentials. No question about that. I'm not sure that it will run in an app pool/web server...

Comment: @Matt ( the OP, weird both OP and answerer have same name) - Add comments, don't enter as answers

Comment: @manojlds OP = Original Poster? it's confusing we have the same name! :) (I'm Matt the answerer below btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-Credential produces a pop up - that will not work from an app pool.

Comment: Sorry manojlds: I'm kinda new here. :) 
@Matt (responder):  Would you know of a way to get the pop-up to work?  Reconfigure IIS or call it another way?  Else, do you know of a work around to get a user to enter their credentials and successfully pass them through to the script?

Comment: @Matt I don't think you could get that to work with that command. I think you'd need to work around it. check out this for a start http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714574.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the "Access is Denied" here is the IIS user attempting to start a process.   True, you won't be able to Get-Credential (because there's no host to ask for the credentials), but, even if you hardcode a credential, you won't be able to start the process.

In most remote contexts, this priv is turned off.

If you want, you could actually make the web application run under an account that actually can launch processes, but, in reading the first paragraph of your question, I can see you're making a mountain out of a molehill:

> I'm attempting to run Powershell scripts through a web interface coded
>   in C#/ASP.Net. I'm leaving my .ps1 scripts intact and calling them
>   through Process.Start(Powershell);.

While this might *seem* easy, it is most definately the hard way (because it pushes you toward this obscure part of the OS - remote execution privs)

If you're running PowerShell in ASP.NET, you should directly use the [PowerShell] API ([See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell%28VS.85%29.aspx)
) to embed PowerShell in .NET.  If you want impersonation to work, you'll also need to follow the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568160/error-executing-powershell-commandlets-using-c/6568919#comment-7752927) to setup your Runspace.

Hope this Helps